# how to draw an image above an Transparent image using CoreGraphics

Tags: iphone

I want to daw an image on an transparent image using coreGraphics can any tell me with the couple of line of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   UIImage *transparentImage = ...;
   [trasparentImage drawInRect:rect]; ///< draw an trasparent image as background.

   UIImage *anImage = ...;
   [anImage drawInRect:rect]; ///< draw an image on an transparent image.

   // get the result from current context
   CGContextRef curCtx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(curCtx);

   ....
}
```

One point: UIImage's draInRect will draw the image on the **current context**. In the UIView's **-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect**, it will push a context into stack. If you want to draw image in the method of self, you need to push a context as current context. Or, you have to create a context and draw the image by **CGContextDrawImage()** method.

Comment: I tried a lot dude its not working fine I will show you some frame ....according to that frame I have to set the Image./Users/priyankmaheshwari/Desktop/Screen shot 2010-12-14 at 3.00.44 PM.png

Comment: I don't know what you tried. Can you provide any codes you tried?

Comment: And I said, if you want to draw image in the method of yourself, you need to push a context as current context.